# Filter a collection to select items that contain a specific string

Tags: c#, list, class, foreach, filter

```
public class abcd
{
    public string sampleA;
    public string sampleB;

    public abcd(string _sampleA, string _sampleB)
    {
        sampleA = _sampleA;
        sampleB = _sampleB;
    }
}

string filter = "Filter";
List<abcd> listA = new List<abcd>();
```

I am trying to figure out how to write a `foreach` statement to retrieve all the class instances in my `listA` that have `sampleA` contain the `string` `filter`.

Basically `foreach`  `abcd` `sampleA` in `listA` that contain `filter` do this...

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: This question needs an improved title, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach(abcd obj in listA.Where(a => a.sampleA.Contains("Filter")))
{
    // ...
}
```

if you want to compare case-insensitive:

```
foreach (abcd obj in listA
    .Where(a => a.sampleA.IndexOf("Filter", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Should the LINQ expression take place before the foreach so that it isn't executed every iteration?

Comment: @NickUdell Now also [it won't be executed in every iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867012/does-foreach-evaluate-the-array-at-every-iteration/19867119#19867119)