# Differences in using List<> returned by a List.FindAll in a foreach loop from using a local List?

Tags: c#, linq

That's just for knowledge, but I wonder if there may be a significant difference between using a local variable that contains a `List<>` returned by `List.FindAll` in a `foreach` loop and calling directly `ListFindAll` inside the `foreach` loop ?

Example here (`m_Project.Resources` is of type `List<Resources.ResourceBase>`):

```
List<Resources.ResourceBase> paletteResources = m_Project.Resources.FindAll(r => r.GetType() == typeof(Resources.PaletteResource));
foreach(Resources.ResourceBase resource in paletteResources)
```

Versus

```
foreach(Resources.ResourceBase resource in m_Project.Resources.FindAll(r => r.GetType() == typeof(Resources.PaletteResource)))
```

Except for the readability, I wonder if there may be performance of thread-related issue using the second method ?
Like the fact that the `foreach` loop would call `List.FindAll` several times, or if by modifying the List in another thread would affect the loop ?

Comment: The Findall is a linq method that will run faster than the foreach.  Linq is using a new library that is optimized better and legacy foreach method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two approaches are practically the same. `foreach` will not call `FindAll` multiple times. `FindAll` is only called once.

This is documented in the language spec (section 8.8.4):

> The above steps, if successful, unambiguously produce a collection
>   type C, enumerator type E and element type T. A foreach statement of
>   the form
>
> ```
>     foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
> ```
>
> is then expanded to:

```
E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
  
 try {
     while (e.MoveNext()) { 
         V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
         embedded-statement
     } 
 } 
 finally { 
     // Dispose e 
 }
```

In your case, `x` would be substituted by `m_Project.Resources.FindAll(r => r.GetType() == typeof(Resources.PaletteResource))`

```
E e = ((C)(m_Project.Resources.FindAll(r => r.GetType() == typeof(Resources.PaletteResource)))).GetEnumerator(); 
 try {
     while (e.MoveNext()) {
```

As you can see, `FindAll` is only called once.

The only difference between the two, I guess, is that if you use the first one, you are left with a local variable `paletteResources`, which you might accidentally use, to mutate some of the `Resources.ResourceBase` objects.

Answer (score 1):

FindAll returns a List. That means there is an object instance "somewhere", So it should not make a difference, wether you save that pointer in a variable, or not.
But for readability and debugging I would suggest to put it there.

Answer (score 1):

There is only a single thread involved and the `FindAll` method will only be called once.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867012/does-foreach-evaluate-the-array-at-every-iteration) answer for more information about how `foreach` loops are treated by the compiler.

The `paletteResources` variable is superfluous, except for readability reasons.